# Read 2 letters in a string using JAVA

Tags: java, string, chars

I need to write a Java program that reads a string and determines if there are these two letters: the lowercase letter “e” or “d”.

That's what i written so far! any ideas why this doesn't work?

```
class ex2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //boolean arg1;
        char e = 'e';
        char d = 'd';
        String x = "This is my test";
        char[] xh = new char[x.length()];
        for(int i=0; i<= x.length();i++) {
            if (xh[i] == e || xh[i] == d) {
                // arg1 = true;
                System.out.println("Correct"); // Display he string
            } else {
                //arg1 = false;
                System.out.println("Wrong");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: 1. you should be getting ArrayOutOfBoundsException as your for loop should not execute for equality check 2. Your xh array is empty

Comment: I do...after printing all "wrong" i get that exception as well.. any ideas?

Comment: use char xh[]=x.toCharArray();

Comment: This is where stepping through your code in your debugger would show you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the simple solution if you want to use it

**NOTE** from comments, you must keep account that *if there is no `e` and `d`, this will iterate twice on the content of the String* but not is second code as second example is just short form of for each

```
String str = "ewithd";
        if (str.contains("e") || str.contains("d")) {
            System.out.println("sucess");
        } else
            System.out.println("fail");
```

if you want to go with array then you can use `foreach()` too

```
char[] ch = str.toCharArray();
        for (char c : ch) {
            if (c == 'e' || c == 'd') {
                System.out.println("success");
            else
                System.out.println("fail");
            }
        }
```

Comment: if there is no `e` and `d`, this will iterate twice on the content of the `String`

Comment: @nicolasFilotto thanks for pointing out i'll put side effects too.. :)

Answer (score 1):

First you have an `ArrayOutOfBound` exception because you need to stop just before the length, i.e. `i<x.length()`.

Now your problem is that you test against an array of `char` that is full of null chars. You need to test against the string :

```
if (x.charAt(i) == e || x.charAt(i) == d) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You never put anything in your array. `char[] xh = new char[x.length()];` simply declares an array of length equal to `x`, it does not set the elements of `xh` to the elements of `x`. Instead, use:

```
char[] xh = x.toCharArray();
```

You also need to change your loop to:

```
for(int i=0; i < x.length(); i++) {
```

to avoid the out of bounds exception you are currently seeing.

Comment: Calling `toCharArray()` will work but it is not a best approach here as it will create new character array which is useless here as we only need to read the content of the `String`

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is the fact that you don't properly iterate over the `char` of your `String`, here is the best way to do it:

```
for (int i = 0, length = x.length(); i < length; i++) {
    char c = x.charAt(i);
    ...
}
```

Assuming that you use **Java 8**, you could rely on the `Stream API` to do the same thing as next:

```
boolean result = x.chars().anyMatch(c -> c == 'e' || c == 'd');
```